# Which event should be used to tidy the display of a TextBox?

Tags: winforms, textbox

When the user leaves a textbox control I want to trim any spaces and immediately update the display with the tidied string.

Should this be done in the Leave, Validating or Validated event?

Thanks

Clarence

Answer (score 1):

I would use leave if you simply want to trim the string. Validating is useful if you want to cancel the leave (from tab, enter click etc) and keep the textbox selected.

Answer (score 0):

The Leave event would be best suited, as it occurs when the focus has left the textbox.